Is there a way to control split screen(Android multi-window) proportions when launching in split mode from the code?
I need to launch an app in split-screen(multi-window) mode but I would like it to be using 30/70 instead of 50/50 from launch, I searched for ways to do this programatically, but so far have not had any luck in achieving this.
I have tried to search for ways to do this using the manifest xml tags, layout maxHeight or defaultHeight, intent flags, ActivityOptionsCompat, display functions and haven't found any way to do it so far, it always launches in 50/50. Does any one know if this is even possible? Thanks in advance.
